# VPS Squid proxy, how to access a remote video from HTML

Tags: proxy, video-streaming, html5-video, squid

I've seen the video below on how to install **Squid** , but in the official doc I can't see how do I access a remote **video** in HTML using Squid.
I suppose I need to create a *node* but not sure how, and how do I reference it in my script:

**HTML**

```
<video id="fplayer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"  
    class="video-js"
    controls
    preload="auto"
    width="640"
    height="264"
    data-setup="{}"
  >
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
        Please enable JavaScript ..</a>
    </p>
    
    <source src="my/vps/path/to/squid/node/myfile.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
       // myfiles.mp4 is actually hosted here: mediafire.com/files/myfile.mp4
</video>
```

https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples  ** Squid Doc

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7BobNN4UJg  ** SSH Install

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think Squid is not the right proxy to achieve what I need.
Express JS is a better tool, and can route the request to stream a video available in the server.
To stream a video from a remote server (eg.mediafire.com) we need to have access to the HTTP Headers (eg. mediafire.com) , which they're not willing to provide.

Comment: Why are you even using Mediafire to play HTML5 video? That site just stores a file and generates download link when user clicks **on their site**. To provide a video from free storage try something like Google Video, DropBox or any other storage site that allows a **direct linking** (sometimes called **hotlinking**) of the uploaded file. Worst case is get free web space (try: 00webhost.com) and use it to store files for later access with direct URL.